# C++ - Static 2d vector not being set

Tags: c++, vector, 2d-vector

I have a static 2-dimensional vector that I'm trying to use in a constructor. The code is as follows:

in `Stage.h`

```
#pragma once

class Stage
{
public:
    Stage();
    virtual ~Stage();    
private:
    typedef std::vector<std::vector<int>> tileMap;
    static tileMap testStageTiles;
};
```

in `Stage.cpp`

```
Stage::Stage()
{
    std::cout << Stage::testStageTiles.size() << std::endl;
}

Stage::~Stage()
{
}

Stage::tileMap Stage::testStageTiles = {
    {1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1}
};
```

Instantiating the class with `Stage _stage;`

But, it always prints out as 0, just wondering why I can't get this vector instantiated?

Comment: Works fine. Please provide a [**Minimal, Complete, Valid Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I suspect there's a global `Stage` object in another translation unit that happens to be constructed before `Stage::testStageTiles` in a static init order fiasco.

Comment: Ah, i believe you're right. I'll look into that.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious the V is Verifiable

Comment: @MattMcNabb Copy/pasted directly from http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - complain to SO.